# YouTube usage statistics by country

Tags: youtube, statistics

I wanted to know if anybody could help me where to find (recent) stats about YouTube´s usage by country.

I am interested in Uruguay but I realize this might be very hard; maybe Argentina is easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most accurate data and I don't know if this is what you wanted, but you can check the [Top Sites in Uruguay](http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/UY) on Alexa.

Comment: I hate Alexa for anything that is not very visited, could be quite off, but, maybe I´ll have to live with it !! Thank you very much!

Comment: It´s been 2 hours since I started searching and have had no luck. Ales´s stats will have to do. Thanks Lipis!